# Not able to mount ccnet on other machine

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

I am trying to mount CruiseContol.NET on other machine.
But I am getting this error

```
Server encountered an internal error. For more information, turn off customErrors in the server's .config file.
```

How can I resolve this issue?
Please help.

Comment: When you say 'mount' do you mean connect to CruiseControl.net via .net Remoting?

Answer (score 0):

Did you turn off custom errors as suggested?
You can do this in *web.config* file, there's an entry:

```
<customErrors mode="On" />
```

or

```
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" />
```

Change this to

```
<customErrors mode="Off" />
```

Then more details should be displayed on the cause of error. Alternatively, the error cause might have been saved to Windows Logs.

Comment: This depends on whether the error is coming from a Web based ccnet service or the .net remoting service.